# Dev C ++ no output

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I am trying to write a simple project on Dev C++ , but it seems it is not working like it should on windows 8.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"hello You~~"<< endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling it, it shows an empty black screen. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using flush() on cout? Maybe you are using different compiler versions resulting in diverse behaviour.

Comment: `endl` implies `flush` and unless the dev-C++ version in question is buggy, that's unlikely to cause any issue. Describe what you did and what happened and do not interpret or paraphrase what's going on in any way at all. For example, it shouldn't do anything after compiling, unless you run the resulting executable. Also, describe what you expect to happen instead. I guess it's working but you fail to see it for some reason unrelated to the program itself.

Comment: I created a new source file : File> Source File. Paste the code, and finally clicked on Compile&Run. Then the black screen shows up, but nothings seems to appear there.

Comment: What happens if you remove the pause and redirect the program output to a file?

Comment: Same result. But I am sure the compiler it is working,because, if I put for example, "cut" instead of "cout", it throws an error.

Comment: What happens if you run the program directly into the command line?

Comment: What happens if you just throw an exception in the code (i.e. type `int i=1/0`), just to make sure you are running the right thing.

Comment: Are you using Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2? If so, change it to Orwell Dev-C++ which works on Windows 8.

Comment: Many users of Avast antivirus seem to have this problem.

Comment: There is a warning message, "[Warning] division by zero". And the black screen freezes.

Comment: @milleniumbug thaanks!! it was the damn antiviurs. Please create an answer so I can mark it as the solution. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There are known issues with running Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 on Windows 8 (it's not that surprising, it's a program from 2005). Try a newer IDE - if you like Dev-C++, you can try Orwell Dev-C++.